# Как вывести строку текста в симуляции RISC-V на Verilator?

Tags: c, ассемблер

У меня есть следующее [задание](https://yadi.sk/i/S2be0-7SnAVOGQ):

> 6. Произвести изменение проекта в соответствии с вариантом задания:
>
>    a. Отредактировать список тестов RISC-V ISA
>      `./sim/tests/riscv-isa/rv32_tests.inc`, оставив только тест, указанный
>      в вашем варианте задания;
>
>    b. Отредактировать `./Makefile` так, чтобы цель `tests` вызывала
>      сборку только выбранного RISC-V ISA теста;
>
>    c. Модифицировать макросы `RVTEST_PASS`, `RVTEST_FAIL` в файле
>      `./sim/tests/common/riscv_macros.h`.
>
> Выдержка из таблицы вариантов с моим заданием:
>
> ```
> +--------+-------------------+--------------+-----+-----------------------------------+
> | Вар. 1 |        Тест       | RESET VECTOR | BUS |        Результат теста            |
> +--------+-------------------+--------------+-----+-----------------------------------+
> |      1 | isa/rv32ui.addi.S |    0x400     | AXI | RVTEST_PASS выводит строку "ok",  |
> |        |                   |              |     | RVTEST_FAIL выводит строку "fail" |
> +--------+-------------------+--------------+-----+-----------------------------------+
> ```

Я не могу понять, как выполнить пункт C, т. е. как я могу вывести строку текста.

#### Мои предположения

Сами макросы `RVTEST_PASS` и `RVTEST_FAIL` [выглядят](https://github.com/Eanmos/scr1/blob/74a22f612e24301ad4fa0d15197c329b29072770/sim/tests/common/riscv_macros.h#L175) (*ссылка на строку файла `riscv_macros.h` из репозитория на GitHub*) следующим образом:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pass/Fail Macro
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

#define RVTEST_PASS                                                     \
        fence;                                                          \
        mv a1, TESTNUM;                                                 \
        li  a0, 0x0;                                                    \
        ecall

#define TESTNUM x28
#define RVTEST_FAIL                                                     \
        fence;                                                          \
        mv a1, TESTNUM;                                                 \
        li  a0, 0x1;                                                    \
        ecall
```

В директории [`sim/tests/common/`](https://github.com/Eanmos/scr1/tree/scr1_sim/sim/tests/common) есть файлы [`sc_print.h`](https://github.com/Eanmos/scr1/blob/scr1_sim/sim/tests/common/sc_print.h) и [`sc_print.c`](https://github.com/Eanmos/scr1/blob/scr1_sim/sim/tests/common/sc_print.c), которые содержат функцию `sc_printf`.

Эта функция используется в тесте [`hello`](https://github.com/Eanmos/scr1/blob/scr1_sim/sim/tests/hello/hello.c), который как раз выводит строку текста:

```
// sim/tests/hello/hello.c

#include "sc_print.h"

int main()
{
    sc_printf("Hello from SCR1!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что мне нужно вставить вызов функции `sc_printf` в макросы `RVTEST_PASS` и `RVTEST_FAIL`? Если да, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: с интерпретацией задания лучше обращаться к тому, кто выдавал это задание... на вскидку всё примерно так... только вот чисто добавить строку в статическую память и передать её функции из макроса с ассемблерной вставкой будет несколько нетривиально... а если посмотреть на реализацию `sc_puts`, то станет видно, что вывод на этой архитектуре судя по всему представляет собой всего лишь запись по адресу памяти, так что может удастся обойтись парой `mov`'ов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Fat-Zer за [наводку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1060451/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-risc-v-%d0%bd%d0%b0-verilator#comment1814958_1060451):

> ```
> static void
> sc_puts(long str, long strlen) {
>   volatile char *out_ptr = (volatile char*)SC_SIM_OUTPORT;
>   const char *in_ptr = (const char*)str;
>   for (long len = strlen; len > 0; --len)
>     *out_ptr = *in_ptr++;
> }
> ```

Как видно, функция `sc_puts` просто побайтно записывает символы строки по адресу `SC_SIM_OUTPORT`. Осталось только написать это на ассембере:

```
/* The constant is from the sc_print.c file. */
#define SC_SIM_OUTPORT (0xf0000000)

/* Stores a character directly to SC_SIM_OUTPORT, assuming
   that a1 = SC_SIM_OUTPORT. */
#define RVTEST_PUTCHAR(c)                                               \
        li a0, (c);                                                     \
        sb a0, 0(a1);

#define RVTEST_PASS                                                     \
        li a1, SC_SIM_OUTPORT;                                          \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('o')                                             \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('k')                                             \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('\n')                                            \
        fence;                                                          \
        mv a1, TESTNUM;                                                 \
        li  a0, 0x0;                                                    \
        ecall

#define TESTNUM x28
#define RVTEST_FAIL                                                     \
        li a1, SC_SIM_OUTPORT;                                          \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('f')                                             \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('a')                                             \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('i')                                             \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('l')                                             \
        RVTEST_PUTCHAR('\n')                                            \
        fence;                                                          \
        mv a1, TESTNUM;                                                 \
        li  a0, 0x1;                                                    \
        ecall
```